# Can the survey request popup be made less obtrusive, please?

Tags: feature-request, status-review, design, collectives, popup

I was looking at a question on SO that happened to be in the Microsoft Azure Collective (I am intentionally not linking it and pixelating the question to avoid causing [the Meta Effect](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/235226) on that post, as the specific post isn't relevant here).

I got this big notification in the middle of the post asking me if I wanted to take a survey:

[image]

If SO really wants me to take the survey, can the notification in the top bar be enough? I find a large notification popup in the middle of the post obtrusive.

I found another post in the Google Cloud collective, which also had a survey popup.

But the survey popup follows along as I scroll, continuing to obstruct the page!

I know I can dismiss it, but I'd rather it not be there and only be the top notification. Or maybe an option to disable survey popups completely? I don't find a popup that follows me as I scroll to be helpful

Comment: [It's just modern site design](https://i.imgur.com/DX88xhz.jpeg)

Comment: @VLAZ that is missing *say no to the "I would like to send notifications!" popup*. How did we end up in the darkest timeline anyway :/

Comment: @VLAZ There's even an [interactive version of it](https://how-i-experience-web-today.com/) (cc Gimby)

Comment: @Lino oh my god, it even shows a popup when you want to leave the site. That's horrible.