# Why do I get a banner "How are we doing? Please help us improve AWS. Take our short survey"?

Tags: discussion, advertising, banner

I just got a new banner on Stack Overflow:

[image]

The survey starts with:

> Thank you for helping us understand your experience with AWS. Sharing your feedback about AWS will help them to make future improvements for you and fellow developers. In this short survey, we'll ask for your input surrounding satisfaction with AWS and should take less than 3 minutes to complete. All of your survey responses will remain anonymous.

---

- Who is *'we'*? AWS themself?
- Why is this asked? Is this a paid survey by AWS (ad)?

The following line:

> Sharing your feedback about AWS will help them to make future improvements for you and fellow developers.

Suggests it is a paid ad. If so, why isn't there any 'Report this ad' or 'Sponsored by AWS' message attached to it?

Comment: You see it because you joined the AWS Collective. The "we" refers to the collective.

Comment: I did not join any collectives, at least, not intended.

Comment: @0stone0: As far as I can see, you are part of the AWS collective. It at least states that on your profile page

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QY5v9.png

Comment: I see, [the collective](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/aws) shows 'joined'. The banner appeared the first time I opened my laptop today, I'm sure I didn't join it today, maybe a while back by accident.

Comment: Leave the collective, and hopefully you won't get those banners.

Comment: Slightly related (though it seems mostly to be about Stack Overflow itself): *[How is the "how are we doing" survey used?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/415230/how-is-the-how-are-we-doing-survey-used)*

Comment: Related: [Can the survey request popup be made less obtrusive, please?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/423416/2821954) for past surveys for other Collectives.

Comment: Tempted to also link to "are survey invitations spam? (Yes, they are)"

Comment: I'm fairly certain you can receive this popup regardless of whether you've joined. Particularly if you're browsing not logged in and visit collective related pages. (Now i'm curous how exactly one joined a collective without realizing it...)

Comment: One does not *join* collectives. One is *assimilated*.

Comment: @ShadowWizardStrikesBack I'm not in the AWS collective and I got it.

Comment: 'Collectives' are antithetical to the sanctity Stack Overflow site and users deserve. One of collectives' goals is ['Brand Awareness'](https://stackoverflow.co/collectives/) - but gaudy ads/surveys and similar distractions are totally out of place in an informational resource that should be free from cruft and bias.

Comment: I just got this for Twilio when I visited a Twilio question. I have certainly never joined a Twilio collective.

Comment: I don't seem to be in the collective either. This is very poor work for creating a survey, the questions seem to be related to SO but it's like someone took a template and forgot to do a Find and Replace or they were meaning the collective and just cocked it up. I'm going to guess all the data is basically useless as I just answered anything to see what was going on and I had no idea if they meant AWS or SO.

Comment: I just got the message again, this time for the 'Google Cloud Collective'. I'm 100% sure I didn't join as you can see [just below the banner itself](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RFJzq.png). This is quite annoying.