# Please don't show Collectives surveys to people who aren't in Collectives

Tags: feature-request, advertising, survey, collectives

I just got a "How are we doing? Help us improve Twilio" banner survey notification when I visited a [twilio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/twilio) question: [Separating User Speech from Chatbot Speech in Real-Time Audio Streams with Twilio and Google Speech-to-Text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76891900/separating-user-speech-from-chatbot-speech-in-real-time-audio-streams-with-twili)

I am not in, nor have I ever been in, the Twilio collective. I have never used Twilio. I have never asked or answered a question tagged with [twilio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/twilio) on Stack Overflow.

Please do not show surveys for products unrelated to Stack Overflow on Stack Overflow. At the very least, please don't show Collectives-based advertising like this survey to users unless they are *in* said Collective.

Comment: Resistance is futile.

Comment: For clarification: is the survey asking about improving the Twilio _Collective_, or Twilio _itself_?

Comment: @RyanM I didn't click the link, so I'm not sure, but I assume it is about Twilio _itself_ since that matches with this similar one for the AWS collective last month: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/425396/why-do-i-get-a-banner-how-are-we-doing-please-help-us-improve-aws-take-our-sh

Comment: I also got the banner, so I just took the plunge. The first question I got is what my experience with Twilio was and the first option in the list was "I don't use this" which I truthfully picked. Then "How likely is it that you are going to use Twilio?" - So I answered "not very likely". "Would you recommend to others?" - not at all likely. I mean I was answering honestly, it is not my fault they ask me questions which really should not be asked to a person that answers they don't use it and it is not likely they are going to be using the product.

Comment: Point being that the type of questions you get seem to suggest it is not tied to if you're in a collective or not, the banner text is simply vague and misleading.

Comment: @RyanM based on the answer below by Berth, would you add [meta-tag:status-review] to the question?

Answer (score 8):

Thank you for providing this feedback. I'd like to clarify that the survey is displayed on questions that are associated with a specific collective, regardless of whether a user is a member of that collective or not. I understand that this might be confusing, especially for users who aren't part of the collective. Additionally, the wording of the banner itself might be a bit misleading, as it's not immediately clear who the "we" refers to in the question "How are we doing?". The goal of this survey is to gather feedback from *users who are viewing content associated with a collective*. I've tracked your feedback and will discuss it with the team to explore potential changes we can make for the survey banner. Once there is an update, I'll update this post.

Comment: *"Once there is an update, I'll update this post."* Any update on this? [I still see the banner](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/425396/why-do-i-get-a-banner-how-are-we-doing-please-help-us-improve-aws-take-our-sh#comment980753_425396), but as I'm not in the collective nor have I answered/asked anything related tho these tags, Why do I get the survery?